# How to add text to matplotlib legend and maintain equal space with legend and plot borders?

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox

I am trying to add text to matplotlib legend which can be done separately by adding annotation but I need them in a single box this is how I have done:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,])
B = A ** 2
C = A ** 3
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plot.plot(A, B, linestyle = '-', marker='^', label='quadratic')
plot.plot(A, C, linestyle = '-', marker='^', label='cubic')
plot.legend(title = 'Lorem ipsum \n' + str(A[1]) + ' dolor sit amet,\nte dolores assentior \ninciderint iu', loc = 'center', bbox_to_anchor = (1.25, 0.5))
plot.set_ylabel('y')
plot.set_xlabel('x')
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

And at the same time I need the spacing between the plot and legend border be same, as the legend width increases the legend should be placed further without changing loc argument, as shown in figure S should be constant:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |     +----------+
|                                                      |     |          |
|                                                      |  S  |          |
|                                                      |<--->|          |
|                                                      |     |          |
|                                                      |     |          |
|                                                      |     |          |
|                                                      |     +----------+
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a simpler method to add text in the legend  and keep spacing constant with options of text alignment in the legend box and so on.